# force VS to autoregen just before compile

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild, components

VB in VS2008 under Windows 7 (64):

I need to change the value of a Property of a Component at some unpredictable time in DesignMode, and want the previously unknown new value to be embedded in the executable that results from VS compilation (as opposed to serializing it to some external file).

I have resorted to a text edit to swap the new value into the autogenerated Component initialization code in a prebuild event handler. This works fine, but it is a little hacky for my taste.   Is there some way instead to force VS to refresh that text?

Comment: To exxpand a little: when I change a Component Property value programmatically, the new value appears in the VS Property Browser, as expected, but is **not** propagated to the autogenerated text.  The trigger for VS autogeneration seems to be some physical action (i.e. mouse or keyboard) by the VS user in the Property Browser.

Comment: (continued)  What I am after is something to trigger autogeneration without depending on user action in the VS UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By luck, I found something that seems to work to force VS to autogenerate initialization code for the runtime instance of a Component, which is what I was after (I needed to have successful communication between designtime and runtime for Components -- easy for Controls, which use the latest designtime BackgroundImage bitmap at runtime (you need only to hide the Property value in the bitmap, which can be done entirely within the rules by using GetPixel and SetPixel).  I considered various hacks, but I hit upon the following, which works and makes sense (though I might be completely FoS about the "why".  If you know better, please educate me):

As I understand it, soon after a Component is dropped on a design surface in VS (and before it is rendered in the Component Tray), Visual Studio adds it to a collection of Components belonging to a Container.  Adding it to the Container's collection is one step in a sequence of happenings that includes Visual Studio's autoregeneration of the Init procedure that will be used for the Component's root at runtime, and which includes values for the Public Properties of the Component.  If you overload the Set Site procedure (the creation of ISite is an early step in  that sequence) for your Component, and set a value for one of its Public Properties in the Overload, **that value will show up in the autoregen text**.   This is almost what I wanted, except that it only worked when VS called Set Site, and I needed it to happen any time I chose.

Then I took a flyer, and in the UI that sets the Property value in question (at some unknowable time), I added code to remove the Component from the Container's collection and then re-add it, hoping that this might again set off a sequence of happenings that would lead to VS again autoregenerating the Init code, this time with the new value of the Property.  It apparently did. Yay.

By deciding when to re-add a Component to the Container's Components collection, I am now able to force VS to write in the autogenerated Init text any value I assign to a Public Property of that Component, and hence embed the value in the executable when it is compiled.

This technique is vulnerable to changes in the (undocumented) way that Microsoft implements autogeneration, and so is arguably a hack.  But even documented features are subject to change.  Backward-compatibility is a nice idea, but sometimes it has to give way.  And delivery is a requirement.  It would be great to know that your code will still be good in any future version of VS, but that, sadly, can't happen, hack or no.

Of course, documented features are in general less subject to change than undocumented ones.  But the logic of autogeneration **after** all the initial Property values are set is pretty compelling.  That Microsoft uses the same sequence later on is not so inherently logical, but doing it a different way would cost Microsoft money for no apparent gain.  And Microsoft and their ilk (are legally required to) make decisions based on the bottom line.  So the status quo seems like a good bet.